# Android JDBC Conn NullPointer

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc

So I´ve been struggling with the JDBC driver to get my MySQL database running in my Android application. It´s a simple application that I have to make for school but I keep getting NullPointers at the Connection class.

I tested the connection in a regular Java project in Netbeans and that works fine.

Here is my code:

private Connection conn;

```
public data_Administration dataAdministration = data_Administration.getInstance();

public data_SQL()
{
    this.connectToDatabase();
}

protected void connectToDatabase()
{
    try
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        }
        catch(Exception ee)
        {

        }

    }
    catch(Exception eee)
    {

    }
    try
    {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://db4free.net:3306/", ****, ****);
    }
    catch (SQLException ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853367/jdbc-vs-web-service-for-android if your connection is to MySQL database outside of your LAN.

Comment: I actually tried it over lan first with my laptop working as database provider. No succes either

Comment: You are ignoring exceptions, **don't do that**.